# Is it possible for Ethereum dApps to port to EOS?

Tags: dapp, ethereum, port-to-eos

If the makers of https://www.cryptokitties.co/ chose to port their dApp to EOS, can they? If yes, what are the point-by-point steps involved in the transition? What are the tools and tech required to make this adjustment?

Answer (score 9):

Well, it is certainly possible.  The contract would have to be rewritten into C++ because Solidity (Ethereum's native programming language) is not supported by the Eosio software.

Traditional software development tools could be used to port the code over to C++ and then it would be compiled into *wasm* (Web Assembly) in order to be executed by the Eosio blockchain.  There is a native tool developed for use with eosio smart contracts, which is used to compile C++ code into *wasm* called ***eosiocpp***.

More information regarding these tools can be found on the wiki! [EOSIO Wiki - Programs & Tools](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Programs-&-Tools)

Answer (score 5):

At the moment you would have to port solidity code (ETH) to C++ (EOS).

<strike>In the future [EOS will support the Ethereum virtual machine](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#scripts--virtual-machines) so it could be possible to use existing solidity codebases with minimal changes.</strike>

<strike>From an [earlier version of the EOS whitepaper](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/477bac64dfaa953e1b5188fca390c8d99ec4714f/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#ethereum-virtual-machine-evm):</strike>

> Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) This virtual machine has been used for
>   most existing smart contracts and could be adapted to work within an
>   EOS.IO blockchain. It is conceivable that EVM contracts could be run
>   within their own sandbox inside an EOS.IO blockchain and that with
>   some adaptation EVM contracts could communicate with other EOS.IO
>   blockchain applications.

**Dan Larimer has confirmed the EVM is no longer a planned feature, you will need to port your code to C++.**

Comment: EOSIO will not support the EVM.

Comment: @bytemaster thanks Dan! Updated my answer to not mislead anyone.