# Does EOS VM support solidity?

Tags: smart-contract, wasm

EOS smart contracts are writeen in c++, but does EOS VM also support (Ethereum's) solidity?

Comment: No, only c++ now, and I don't think it will support solidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official eos developer guide

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/required-knowledge

It doesn't support solidity now. It only supports c++ but they have also mentioned that there are other languages which will be supported in the future.

Rust, Python, and Solidity will be supported in the future updates.

Comment: just to clarify: that article doesn't claim any of those languages will be supported at any point, and blockone is not working on it. they only mention that 3rd party teams work on it, but there's no guarantee any of these projects will be finalised and maintained

Answer (score 1):

Dan mentioned in [a comment](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/176/is-it-possible-for-ethereum-dapps-to-port-to-eos/204#comment150_204) on this website that "EOSIO will not support the EVM."

However, if a Solidity to WASM compiler will exist, then Solidity can be supported.